# How do you segue more than 1 image referring Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, parse-platform, segue

Following this Question/Answer

https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquerytableviewcontroller-segue

I would like to know how do you set the code on passing more than 1 image. Is there a way to make the UIImageView Reusable? (Like a CollectionView Cell)

This would be the code to follow for 1 Image coming from the cell clicked.

EDITED CODE:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

static int index = 1;

PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", index++]];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


}
}];

return cell;
}
```

How can I make the cell reusable and show more images?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking.. What do you mean by "make it reusable and show more images"? If you are asking what I think you're asking then you can make a `static int index = 0;` inside that function and do: `[self.vestimenta objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", index++]];`

Comment: That is absolutely right! THANK YOU!

Comment: Hmm..How do I keep the Image in the UIImageView? Once I've seen it it once no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking if you can change the image that's installed in an image view once it's been created? If so, the answer is most definitely yes.

You can replace the image in an image view as many times as you want. The same goes for the images loaded into buttons, but you have to use a special method for that.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to show the images but once viewed they disappear. Do you know how to keep images in their cells even after they have been viewed? I have updated my code.

Comment: What do you mean "once viewed they disappear?" You make it sound like they disappear as soon as you look at them. That seems unlikely. Do they appear for a split second and then disappear spontaneously? Do they appear the first time the collection items are shown, but disappear if you scroll away and then scroll back? Please update your post with more information.

Comment: Sorry about that. They disappear after I scroll away and then scroll back.